# How to make a dropdown menu in a dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a dropdown menu for a website. I got the first segment working, but when I want to make one element to show other options on its right side, it's just not working.

It's just some basic HTML and CSS setting, I am just a beginner. I've tried decluttering the code and doing it in the simplest way possible.

```css
li a, dropbtn {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #111;
}


li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;

}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;

}

.two {
   display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
margin-top: -40px;
margin-left: 160px;

}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;


}

.dropdown-content a:hover {

  background-color: #f1f1f1;

  }
```

```html
<!-- About section -->
<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropbtn">About</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="mission.html">Mission</a> 
            <div class="two">
              <a href="team.html">Team</a>
            </div>  

      <a href="mission.html">Our Story</a>
      <a href="mission.html">Partners</a>
      <a href="team.html">Team</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

I would like to understand what I am doing wrong, and how can I make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `+` sign to select the sub menu in css and make it `display:block`. Check below code:

```
.dropdown-content a:hover + div {
   display:block;
}
```

See the Snippet below:

```css
li a, dropbtn {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color:gray;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #111;
}


li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;

}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;

}

.two {
   display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
margin-top: -40px;
margin-left: 160px;

}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;


}

.dropdown-content a:hover {

  background-color: #f1f1f1;

  }
  
.dropdown-content a:hover + div {
   display:block;
}
```

```html
<!-- About section -->
<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropbtn">About</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="mission.html">Mission</a> 
            <div class="two">
              <a href="team.html">Team</a>
            </div>  

      <a href="mission.html">Our Story</a>
      <a href="mission.html">Partners</a>
      <a href="team.html">Team</a>
       
            <div class="two">
              <a href="ceo.html">CEO</a>
            </div>  

    </div>
</li>
```